# GitLab Runner using the Helm Chart - point to private repo

Tags: docker, kubernetes, gitlab, gitlab-ci-runner, kubernetes-helm

I have a kubernetes namespace that I want to leverage for Gitlab runners. I installed the runners following the [Helm Chart](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/install/kubernetes/gitlab_runner_chart.html) instructions. The problem I am running into is that when the job container spins up, I get the following 
ERROR:

Job failed: image pull failed: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = Get https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/: net/http: request canceled while waiting for connection (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers)

It's trying to connect to the public docker repo but my organizations firewall is blocking it. How would I go about having the instace go to our private repo?

Any help would be greatly appreciated as I've been stuck on this issue for some time now :(

Answer (score 2):

I would presume you'll need to specify a `values.yaml` to the `helm install` that points to your mirrored copy of the images it needs. So:

- [gitlab/gitlab-runner](https://gitlab.com/charts/gitlab-runner/blob/1e329394f69b80003a43c503e7d11eb6463d008a/values.yaml#L4)
- [busybox](https://gitlab.com/charts/gitlab-runner/blob/1e329394f69b80003a43c503e7d11eb6463d008a/values.yaml#L14)
- [ubuntu](https://gitlab.com/charts/gitlab-runner/blob/1e329394f69b80003a43c503e7d11eb6463d008a/values.yaml#L87)

or whatever ones you wish to use for the `init` and `runner: image:`

Since you already have the chart deployed, I am fairly certain you can just do an ["helm upgrade"](https://github.com/helm/helm/blob/v2.10.0/docs/using_helm.md#helm-upgrade-and-helm-rollback-upgrading-a-release-and-recovering-on-failure) that changes only those values:

```
helm upgrade --set "image=repo.example.com/gitlab/gitlab-runner" \
    --set "init.image=repo.example.com/etc-etc" \
    [and so forth] \
    $releaese_name $chart_name
```

*(substituting the release name and the name of the chart as your helm knows it, of course)*